# Quebra de texto em coluna de relatório Windows Reporting (RDLC)

Tags: c#, winforms, relatório

Tenho um relatório que possui a estrutura abaixo:

[image: Estrutura do relatório]

E, quase, tudo funciona corretamente. Porém quando o texto da resposta de uma pergunta é muito grande (não possui limite de caracteres) a linha inteira (do relatório) é movida para uma outra página ao invés de fazer a quebra de linhas do conteúdo.

Este comportamento faz com que em algumas situações exista um grande espaço em branco entre as páginas do relatório.

Gostaria de saber como, ou o que devo fazer para realizar a quebra de linhas do conteúdo da célula da coluna `Resposta`.

Comment: nunca usei Windows Reporting, mas tenta dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760570) do SOen.

Comment: Funcionou @Mateus, era exatamente isto que eu estava procurando. Se quiser responder eu marco como resposta.

Comment: Ok, deixei o link como referência e coloquei o conteúdo na resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760570) no SOen, altere a propriedade `KeepTogether` do seu TextBox para *true*, para manter na mesma página, ou para *false*, para quebrar para outra página.